# Global section of a closed point as a divisor for a degree 2 curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry

This is part of Ex1.7 in Chapter IV of Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry. Let $X$ be a curve of degree $2$ and genus $2$ over $\mathbb{P}^1$. Show that the canonical divisor defines a complete linear system of degree $2$ and dimension $1$ without base points. I use RR Thm $h^0(D)-h^0(K-D)=d+1-g$. Let $D=K$. Then I can get the degree and dimension easily. But for the base point freeness, I let $D=K-P$ for any closed point $P$ and use the criterion in Proposition3.1 in the same chapter(saying that a complete linear system $|D|$ is base point free iff for every $P\in X$, $\dim|D-P|=\dim|D|-1$). In other words, I get $h^0(K-P)=h^0(P)$ and want to show $h^0(P)=1$. However, I think it should be $2$, because $H^0(X,P)=\{f\in k(X)|div(f)+P\geq 0\}$ and $f$ can be spanned by either constant or functions having one pole at $P$(it cannot have higher degree vanishment at $P$ since $deg(div(f))=0$ and if it did, $div(f)+P$ would not be effective). Can anyone tell me what my mistake is?

Comment: There are no functions with a simple pole at a single point in your case.

Comment: @Mohan Why not? Can you explain a little more?

Comment: If such a function existed, it gives a morphism $X\to\mathbb{P}^1$ of degree one, which says $X$ is isomorphic to the projective line and thus genus zero.